# iPad MapKit - Reselecting one pin does not work

Tags: objective-c, touch, mapkit

I have the following problem:

I have a number of pins on my map. After touching one, a custom popup opens and displays information. This works perfect.

My problem is, that if you select the same pin twice, the popups does not open, you have to touch another one or click some where in the map.

My code is the following:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;
    CPPointOfInterest *myAnnotation = (CPPointOfInterest*) annotation;

    if ([myAnnotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] || myAnnotation.poi_id <= 0) {
        return nil;

    } else {
        NSString* identifier = @"Pin";
        MKPinAnnotationView* annView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mv_map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if(nil == annView) {
            annView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
        }

        [annView addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:@"selected"
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                 context:@"GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED"];

        if(self.nearest_poi == myAnnotation) {
            annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

        } else {
            annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

        }

        annView.animatesDrop = YES;

        annotationView = annView;

        [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
        [annotationView setCanShowCallout:NO];

        return annotationView;

    }
}
```

Observer:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context{

    NSString *action = (NSString*)context;
    if([action isEqualToString:@"GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED"]){
        BOOL annotationAppeared = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] boolValue];
        if (annotationAppeared) {
            // show popup
            } 
    }
}
```

I have also tried the didSelectAnnotationView methode, this also just works for the first click event.

I have searched for several hours, but nothing to find... :/

Does anybody knows a solution for my problem, please give me a hint...

Thanks and greetings,
Mathew

Answer (score 3):

You have to deselect the annotation through the mapView before you can select it again.  Try the folowing:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{

[mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a popover to display the info:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    if (popover)
    {
        [popover release];
        popover = nil;
    }

    LocatorSearchDealer *dealer = [[mapView selectedAnnotations] objectAtIndex:0];

    //without this line I cannot immediately reselect the same annotation.
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:dealer animated:NO];
}
```